# Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml declared with prefix fb but no taglibrary exists for that namespace

Tags: jsf, facebook-javascript-sdk, facelets

I am developing an application for FB Login with website using Javascript. I tried in html it works fine. when i convert into JSF it gives an error.

This is my `fbLogin.xhtml` code.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <h:head>
        <title>FB Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body styleClass="ice-skin-rime">   

   <fb:login-button scope="email"></fb:login-button> 
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<APP_ID>',
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here

    showMe = function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 'connected') {
        div.innerHTML = '<em>Not Connected</em>';
      } else {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var i=0;
          for (var key in response) {

            i++;

            switch(i){
            case 1: document.getElementById("formId:id").value=response[key]; break;
            case 2: document.getElementById("formId:name").value=response[key]; break;
            case 5: document.getElementById("formId:link").value=response[key]; break;
            case 6: document.getElementById("formId:userName").value=response[key]; break;
            case 19: document.getElementById("formId:email").value=response[key]; break;
           }  

          }

        });
      }
    };
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    showMe(response);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', showMe);
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>  

       <h:form id="formId">
        <table>
        <tr><td><a>ID : <h:inputText id="id" value="#{fbLogin.id}" /> </a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a>Name : <h:inputText id="name" value="#{fbLogin.name}" /> </a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a>Link : <h:inputText id="link" value="#{fbLogin.link}" /> </a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a>User Name : <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{fbLogin.userName}" /> </a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><a>E-Mail : <h:inputText id="email" value="#{fbLogin.email}" /> </a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{fbLogin.Display}" /></td></tr>                                      
        </table>    
      </h:form>         
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The reason for writing code with JSF is, i need to get user information in to my backBean for store into database.

when i try to run this app, i got warning in browser as :

`Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml declared with prefix fb but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.`

What is the error in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get this when you have set `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Development` in webapp's `web.xml` and Facelets encounters a XML namespace which it could not resolve to a JSF compatible tag library. This warning is just displayed to inform a (starting) developer about a possible unforeseen typo in the XML namespace or mistake in tag library configuration.

However, the XML namespace in question in this particular case [actually](http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml) referring an external Facebook JavaScript API, not a JSF tag library such as PrimeFaces, OmniFaces, etc. Your code is completely fine.

You can just ignore this warning. This warning won't appear when you set the JSF project stage back to `Production`, or when you remove the whole context parameter (it defaults to `Production` already).

Comment: yeah, i changed my configuration file as you have told. Now the problem is my '<fb:login-button scope="email"></fb:login-button>'  tag button is not showing in my webpage.!!

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, just press "Ask Question" button in right top. That question is completely unrelated to the one currently asked.