# How to display FB-Login Button in JSF page?

Tags: facebook, jsf, xhtml

I am developing an application for FB Login with website using Javascript and JSF. I have included my FB-Login button tag `<fb:login-button scope="email"></fb:login-button>`  inside my code. when i run it, it does't show login button in my webpage. I am using Eclipse Juno editor and Apache Tomcat 7.0. How do i get Login button in my webpage? The thing is, it works fine in html.

I have attached my `fbLogin.xhtml` code at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263746/warning-this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace-http-www-facebook-com-2008-fbml-dec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your body tag as `<body></body>` not by this `<h:body></h:body>` and place `<fb:login-button scope="email" />` before `<h:form>` tag.

Example:

```
<body>
     <fb:login-button scope="email" />

            <h:form>
             ... 
            </h:form>
<body>
```

Now it will work fine.

Comment: This still didn't work for me.  I get "fb:login-button" is not bound.

Comment: @sgoldberg see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263746/warning-this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace-http-www-facebook-com-2008-fbml-dec..

Answer (score 1):

you can make it as JS also

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[

document.write('<fb:login-button scope="email" />');

//]]>
</script>
```