# How to ignore svg namespace warning in jsf

Tags: svg, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a similar problem as this post: [Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml declared with prefix fb but no taglibrary exists for that namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263746/warning-this-page-calls-for-xml-namespace-http-www-facebook-com-2008-fbml-dec)

However, in my case, the error is related to SVG elements. I'm attempting to include inline svg:

```
<div>
  <ui:include src="img/foo.svg" />
</div>
```

And this is the error I get:

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.w3.org/2000/svg declared with prefix path but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

I know that I'm supposed to just ignore the error, but I don't want an error showing up at all. Currently a `p:growl` shows up with that message. How do I turn of the growl for that particular message? I don't want to remove the `p:growl` tag completely from the page since it's used for other meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

So is your SVG just an image you could use OmniFaces [o:graphicImage](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) like...

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{images.get(image.id)}" type="svg" />
```

In your web.xml add...

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Or if you want to just render the SVG right on the page with NO image just the raw SVG we have done this before..

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bean.mySvg}" />
```

Where bean.mySVG is a String representation of your "img/foo.svg" you load from disk.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to have to use the `<h:outputText>` technique, but I was hoping I could use `<ui:include>`. I want the SVG rendered directly on the page -- I do not want it inside an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Got it .  We had to do the same thing and used the h:outputText trick with escape="false" to render the raw SVG to the DOM.

Comment: Also you might have to when you load your SVG from disk strip off the <xml> header and a few other lines before sending it to the browser.